# What is different between h.265/HEVC in a container(mp4, mkv....) and h.265/HEVC Annex B raw file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec, video-encoding

What is different between h.264/HEVC in a container (mp4, mkv....) and h.265/HEVC Annex B raw file? I mean about codec, pixel formats and why can't hevc Annex B contain audio stream?

I researched google for a while but I couldn't understand it fully yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annex B just a method of inserting separators (specifically, the byte sequence 000001) between chunks data to identify where decodable units or blocks begin and end. The byte sequence, called a start code, do not indicate anything about the data itself. So If you want to multiplex audio and video together, you must also add information to the start code to indicate whether the next chunk is audio or video. And in the case of multi track audio, what track it belongs to. And sense we already have a handful of container available, we don't need to create a new one.
Annex B exists solely as a way for codec authors to create a standard output format that container authors can read to create full media files.

Comment: Thanks. So a codec format(.hevc, .h264.....) can't contain both audio and video right? and if i want to multiplex audio then i need a different container that can do the job,am i right?

Comment: A raw bitstream, whether HEVC or AVC or anything else, is exactly one stream without any encapsulation or metadata. The bitstream format (Annex B or length-prefixed) is irrelevant.